# How to use an A~Z key as a modifier for a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I want to set up shortcut that has a letter as a modifier key. In other words, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, where M must be pressed before S. I believe this is is how the feature is supposed to work - correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

[image: Keyboard shortcut using a letter as a modifier key]

As I have it now, the "M" key is being ignored and it registers as <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, (which will Clear Scale) instead.

What do I need to do to make this actually work? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl + 2 already perform this command?

Comment: @RickRiggs It does. But not for those of us who use Emulate NumPad.

Comment: You can use the home row #2 as well.

Comment: @RickRiggs Hmmm, you mean Ctrl + the 2/@ key, right? I suppose I don't use that now, so I'll consider doing that for this particular shortcut. I still want to know how to use a letter as a modifier though. Actually, I thought it would be nice for consistency to use Alt+M+ different letters for different Modifiers.

Comment: Yes that's the key. on your inquiry, I totally agree - I would like to know this answer as well, so I didn't really want to post this as an answer. If I were to take a complete guess at your particular problem though, it would seem that this is failing because Both Alt+M & Alt+S are assigned to something, so no matter the order, it would have to ignore both of those functions.

Comment: @RickRiggs What's odd is that no other command uses Alt+M in Object Mode (although it is Merge in Edit Mode). I would expect Blender to therefore recognize that I've assigned it as a modifier and while Alt+M is pressed, listen for the S key, and once pressed carry out the command.

Comment: It works for me with 2 keys (without regular key as modifier) if using `Alt` as modifier key and `M` after it. If using 3 keys (with regular pressed as modifier) I found it working if setting *Release* instead of *Press*.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks! Good observation! Unexpected behavior, too. I just tested it and unfortunately it *also* clears the scale. I did another test adding a Solidify Modifier with **object.modifier_add** and Alt+M+Y... it worked only because Y is not assigned to anything else, and if I set it to "Release" instead of "Press" it adds *two* Solidify Modifiers!